# Which is more important for a tanks survivability, Toughness or Vitality?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I am building my Gaurdian to be very tanky but I can't help but wonder. Which stat provides more survivability? Toughness or Vitality? Is it situational?

Comment: Short answer, Vitality. There are armor-ignoring attacks, and Vitality will serve you better against those. However, Toughness does increase your effective health when it's not ignored. So invest in both trait lines leaning a little more on Vitality. Unfortunately the math on armor is not set in stone, so I can't give numbers. The good news is that most items in Guild Wars 2 provide both Toughness and Vitality in equal amounts (Hearty weapons, Lapis accessories), so you probably won't have to make a choice between the two in gear, only in trait lines.

Comment: Yep for my guardian i placed my trait lines full in the vitality and toughness tree. Nice survivability with a 2 hander.

Comment: What mode are you playing? (PvP, PvE, WvW)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some trade-offs. Overall, I consider Vitality to be a little better, but it will depend on your build, as well as the enemy you're fighting.

**Toughness**

- Toughness reduces the amount of damage you take from a given attack. Builds that focus on toughness will have a smaller health pool, but receive less damage to make up for it.
- The main disadvantage of stacking toughness is that some attacks ignore it. This includes damage over time from conditions.
- The main advantage of toughness is that it keeps your health pool smaller, allowing you to heal more efficiently.

**Vitality**

- Vitality increases your health pool. Builds that focus on vitality will take more damage than toughness builds, but are able to absorb more before dying.
- The main advantage of vitality-heavy builds is that the extra health cannot be circumvented, like toughness can.
- The main disadvantage of vitality is that a huge health pool is more difficult to heal up.

**Conclusion**

It's probably wise to have some mix of these two stats. In general, I would favor Vitality. Of course, the more you have of both, the more tanky you will be.

If you have ways to mitigate damage-over-time conditions, Toughness might be advantageous, since you can avoid much of the downside. Likewise, if you have very poor healing ability, you might want to stack Toughness so you don't have a massive health pool you're unable to refill.

If you have ample heals, especially some form of continuous healing, Vitality will probably be more advantageous, as you can keep that huge health pool refilled.

Comment: Actually, constant healing (like the Guardian has access to), makes *Toughness* more valuable (and overhealing is rarely an issue in Guild Wars). The reason is simple: you can think of Toughness as multiplying your hitpoints, in terms of effective health. This makes heals on a target with lots of toughness provide a greater increase in "Effective Health" than if they had mostly vitality alone.

Comment: Suggested addition: Toughness makes you better against flat damage attacks, but Vitality makes you better against condition damage-over-time (which is "true" damage).

Comment: Also worth noting is some classes have more base HP than others. For classes like Necro and Warrior who have the most HP, I think it's more useful to up Toughness.

Answer (score 0):

A tanky guard needs:

Toughness,

Regen - from traits (Absolute Resolution!), food, and Runes (Dolak for example)

Healing - Healing Points!, Mace, traits AH or Monks, dodge heals,

Condition removal or/and Condition duration reduction.

Blocks!

I find 3,400 toughness good enough to take a burst and to survive. You need passive healing and several active heals, plus dodge rolls to heal. Guardians have silly amounts of healing if traited so. Balancing your other play styles to suit is the key.

Personally I rate Toughness over Vitality as it also plays into high crit builds with  Retributive Armor. I melt less in sPvP!

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use a lot of different build types but one of the cheapest and effective builds I use on warrior is toughness vitality and condi damage. Sword shield longbow. 2 shout heals for hp and utility/extra damage. And endure pain on the bar and in the traits with defiant stance as a heal. This gives me about 30k hp over 3k armor and I use the cleanse trait when you use burst skills the condi removal on weapon swap and burst skill that conserves Adrinaline plus the Adral health. And the soldiers focus. And getting up from might . It’s a solid build that I have consistently used for years to fight every meta and still stay on top. Generally can fight multiple people and kill most things if you time your shield bash right. Your immob bleeds burns are constant. Your condi removal is constant and you have actives to use. Your armor is high for physical attacks. No is high for burst attacks. You regen like a mad man. And you can pop out what 10-12 seconds of invuln plus defiant stance is one of my favorite heals since when you finally get me low and try and pop me or I see a big burst coming I can use it and sit there holding them down with my immob and cut them up.